# Error Hosting WCF 3.5 Under IIS Express

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, .net-3.5, iis-express

I'm trying to run WCF Service based on 3.5 Framewor on Windows 8 with Visual Studio 2012 and IIS Express.

Service hosting fails with error "HTTP Error 404.17".

I'm trying with default Visual Studio WCF template setting framework 3.5.
Works fine if I select frameworks 4.0 or 4.5.

Is there a way to make 3.5 services works fine with IIS Express?

Http activation is enabled in Windows Features.
Tried install, re-install, remove and install Service Model via:
Framework64\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation> .\ServiceModelReg.exe -i

Still not working.

Regards,
Dmitry

Comment: Worked around that by moving to IIS instead IIS Express.